# Using Java 7 HashMap in Java 8

Tags: java, performance, hashmap

I have updated a Java application to Java 8. The application heavily relies on HashMaps.
When I run the benchmarks, I see unpredictable behavoir. For some inputs, the application runs faster than before, but for larger inputs, it's constantly slower.

I've checked the profiler and the most time consuming operation is HashMap.get. I suspect the changes
are due to the HashMap modification in Java 8, but it may not be true, as I have changed some other parts.

Is there an easy way that I hook in the original Java 7 HashMap into my Java 8 application so that I only change the hashmap implementation to see if I still observe the change in performance.

The following is a minimal program that tries to simulate what my application is doing. 
The basic idea is that i need to share nodes in the application. At some runtime point, a node
should be retrieved or created if it already does not exist based on some integer properties. The following only uses two integer, but in the real application I have one, two and three integer keys.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

public class Test1 {

static int max_k1 = 500;
static int max_k2 = 500;

static Map<Node, Node> map;
static Random random = new Random();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        run();
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println((end - start) / 1000_000);
    }
}

private static void run() {
    map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10_000_000; i++) {
        Node key = new Node(random.nextInt(max_k1), random.nextInt(max_k2));
        Node val = getOrElseUpdate(key);
    }
}

private static Node getOrElseUpdate(Node key) {
    Node val;
    if ((val = map.get(key)) == null) {
        val = key;
        map.put(key, val);
    }
    return val;
}

private static class Node {

    private int k1;
    private int k2;

    public Node(int k1, int k2) {
        this.k1 = k1;
        this.k2 = k2;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 17;
        result = 31 * result + k1;
        result = 31 * result + k2;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;

        if (!(obj instanceof Node))
            return false;

        Node other = (Node) obj;

        return k1 == other.k1 && k2 == other.k2;
    }
  }
}
```

The benchmarking is primitive, but still, this is the result of 15 runs on Java 8:

```
8143
7919
7984
7973
7948
7984
7931
7992
8038
7975
7924
7995
6903
7758
7627
```

and this is for Java 7:

```
7247
6955
6510
6514
6577
6489
6510
6570
6497
6482
6540
6462
6514
4603
6270
```

The benchmarking is primitive, so I appreciate if someone who is familiar with JMH or other benchmarking tools run it, but from what I observe the results are better for Java 7. Any ideas?

Comment: This is tricky, as there is [another report to suggest](http://java.dzone.com/articles/hashmap-performance) a 20% improvement in performance with `HashMap#get`.  It'd be difficult to answer this question without seeing a typical use case of your maps, and why the `get` operation is the bottleneck.  Could you add some info to your question to provide us with similar code so that we could also observe the performance hits?

Comment: "I assume the changes are due to the HashMap modification" don't assume

Comment: @NimChimpsky:  [There definitely is an implementation difference](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/HashMap.java/?v=diff&id2=7u40-b43) that would cause a change in performance.

Comment: Insofar as the greater question, it might be the case that you copy the source code from Java 7 wholesale, put it in a temporary location, hook *that* in instead, and run with it.  But the true solution would come from a more efficient data structure.

Comment: @NimChimpsky I think suspect is a better word. The thing is that this is my first guess. That's why I think it's logical if I can hook in a Java 7 implementation and see what happens.

Comment: It seems the Java8 HashMap uses trees (for larger (size > 8) maps) with not settable threshold for change: http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/HashMap.java/?v=diff&id2=7u40-b43#146

Comment: @Makoto I'm thinking of how I can reproduce the whole problem in a simple code, but it may not be easy. I think your suggestion is fine to just copy the code and run the application.

Comment: I'm looking into that as a viable solution now, but it'd require you to copy over more than just that class, as it makes use of package-visible member variables.

Comment: I would bet good money that the source of your issue is not preformance degradation from jvm 7 -> 8, but in fact different data/impl elsewhere

Comment: but yeah, just copy the hasmap implemention from 7 and use it ...

Comment: So - `sun.misc.Hashing` was used in Java 7, and I'm willing to bet that it's been since removed in Java 8.  You may be at an impasse with just copying over the code.

Comment: @Makoto do you know any third party library that provides an implementation similar to Java 7 HashMap?

Comment: None off of the top of my head.  I think a better answer would come if you provided an example of what your HashMap usage was instead of trying to go back to the old way.  It could be the case that you've hit an edge case with the new implementation; it could also be the case that you have to change how you're working with them, too.

Comment: Ok, I will think about it to see if I can come up with a minimal example and will update the question.

Comment: [Makoto](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1079354/makoto)'s suggested link shows a performance increase of java 8. And you are telling - "For some inputs, the application runs faster than before, but for larger inputs, it's constantly slower." Then you may have a look at your hashCode() method - how the hash code is generated. Though I'm not pretty sure about this.

Comment: @Razib that can also be the case. The thing is that Java 8 hashmap also changes the implementation of hash() method that was responsible for shuffling hashcode. Maybe my hashcode is not good enough for Java 8. There may also be other factors.

Comment: @GáborBakos: It only uses trees when a single hash bucket has > 8 entries -- not the map as a whole --  which is a strong indicator that you have a bad hash function.

Comment: @LouisWasserman You are right. Sorry, I just grepped for the threshold and not interpreted properly. That makes much more sense. :) Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @Makoto I added an example, so you can take a look.

Comment: Maybe try a more aproperiate initial size for the hashmap so you get less collission while it is growing. `new HashMap<>(1000)`. However since you do have very much collissions it wont help much. I do actually wonder why java 7 is better in this case at it has to linear search. can you show us the Node.hashCode()?

Comment: @eckes it's there, you need to scroll down a bit :-)

Comment: Ah thanks. (I guess there are nearly no duplicates or duplicate hashcodes? strange).

Comment: The node is NOT Comparable, so the implementation change should not have any effect (from javadoc: To ameliorate impact, when keys are Comparable, this class may use comparison order among keys to help break ties.)

Comment: Over that particular range (two integers between 0 and 499), that hash function may not be ideal. For the 250,000 possible `Node` values it only has 15969 hash codes. If this is the real range of your objects, perhaps you should change the hash function to `500 * k1 + k2`, which will give you completely unique hash codes over this range.

Comment: A JMH tests show same performance degregation for Java 8 (and actually independend of initial hash size). I compared also a better hashCode distribution, this makes the overall time 3,5 times faster and Java 8 is better than 7: https://gist.github.com/ecki/9f69773eb29428a36077
I guess having 8-16 collisions is the most hurtful thing you can do with the tree implementation in Java8.

Comment: Updated my test with a comparator, it now shows that with comparator Java 8 is faster for good and badly distributed hashes, and without comparator java 7 is faster for badly distributed hashes (only).

Comment: @Ali I sparked a discusion on OpenJDK core-libs-dev mailing list, where we are discussing and modifying my JMH benchmarks. Would you be willing to sent a mail to the list in response to and state that it is OK with you, if we use BSD-2clause license with your original code or that you do not claim any copyright on it or similar? http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2015-January/030733.html

Comment: @eckes Any license is fine with me. The discussion on the mailing list is very long and I didn't read it all. Can you send me the link of the specific post that someone asks about license? Or should I just all of the sudden post that use it in anyway you want?

Comment: @Ali Thanks! looks like we are fine. The further improved tests are here http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~plevart/jdk9-dev/HM.comparableClassFor/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your `hashCode()` is very poor. In example you posted you have 250000 unique values but only 15969 unique hash codes. Because of lot of collisions, [Java 8 swaps lists with trees](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/180). In your case it only adds overhead, because many elements not only have the same position in hash table but also the same hash code. The tree ends up as a linked list anyway.

There are couple of ways to fix this:

1. Improve your hashCode. `return k1 * 500 + k2;` resolves the issue.
2. Use [THashMap](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/hash/THashMap.html). Open addressing should work better in case of collisions.
3. Make `Node` implement `Comparable`. This will be used by `HashMap` to construct balanced tree in case of conflicts.

Comment: And the reason Java 7 behaves better may be attributed to the fact that its hash() function provides better shuffling to shield against such cases?

Comment: @Ali no I think the reason is that Java 7 does not use the rather expensive tree structure on a collision but a linear list (which is bad for larger number of collisions but seems to have lower cost for the small number in your case).

Comment: I agree with @eckes. Shuffling doesn't matter when hash codes are identical. The tree is slower because for identical hash codes and non-Comparable elements it acts as linked list with unnecessary overhead.

Comment: I think with the idendityHashcodde based tie breaker there is actually a balanced tree when you have no comparable. I am just not sure how well it behaves, especially not if you use new keys instead of reusing instances.

Comment: Java 8 appears slower because the technique it uses to try to improve performance in the case of hash collisions is hurt even worse when a hash function is as bad as yours was.